# Why doesn't my Android 9 app open automatically on a TV screen after restart, while it works on the emulator?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-9.0-pie

**AssistantReceiver.java**

```
public class AssistantReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
            context.startActivity(context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName()));
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".AssistantReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I restart the Android 9 emulator (It is TV screen), the app opens automatically because the receiver is functioning properly. However, when I try the same on a real Android 9 TV screen, the app does not open when I turn off and turn on again the screen, which suggests that the receiver might not be working. Could you please help me understand the reason for this discrepancy? Is there something that I might have missed?

Comment: Have you tried adding a log in the receiver and seeing if it gets called? It might be working but the startActivity call might be getting blocked by the system (very common in chinese devices)

Comment: @Iscle Yes, I attempted to add a toast message and repeated it for 1 minute. While the toast message appeared on the emulator, it did not appear on the actual TV.

Comment: @Iscle [I read this article also.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

Comment: A toast might also get blocked, use a Log.d call to see if it gets printed to logcat. Which TV is it?

Comment: @Iscle But the Log.d statement will not be printed because the app is closed.

Comment: When a receiver is called (by the system or any other app) the app is instantiated and thus, the logcat will be printed. If it does not get printed it means the receiver is not being called.

Comment: @Iscle I cannot do it because the real TV screen exists in the company, and I always have to send the APK to another programmer to install the app on the TV. Additionally, I am working remotely. Due to these factors, printing messages in the Log.d is a little more challenging in this situation.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure how to help you. Your code looks good, and if it works in the emulator it should also work in the TV, but it must be that the OEM has modified default Android behaviour. Maybe there's a setting in Settings to allow the app to open from the background.

Comment: @Iscle I will try to find someone who owns an Android 9 TV screen from a different factory to test the app. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` action to your receiver:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AssistantReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I tried to find `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` on the Android documentation but could not locate it. I believe it does not exist.